# How to execute the function one by one by synchronized?

Tags: android, multithreading, synchronized

I use the `MPChart` to draw the multiple Chart. And I want it to draw one by one.

SO I use the following code:

```
private class ChartThread implements Runnable{
        String[] list;
        String TAG;
        private ChartThread (String[] list , String TAG) {
            this.list= list;
            this.TAG = TAG;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized(this) {
                mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        showOnMPChart(list , TAG);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

And use the following code to call thread:

```
    ChartThread  myRunnable1 = new ChartThread (getStringArray1(),TAG_mpchart_first);
    Thread myThread1=new Thread(myRunnable1);
    myThread1.start();

    ChartThread  myRunnable2 = new ChartThread (getStringArray2(),TAG_mpchart_second);
    Thread myThread2=new Thread(myRunnable2);
    myThread2.start();

    ChartThread  myRunnable3 = new ChartThread (getStringArray3(),TAG_mpchart_third);
    Thread myThread3=new Thread(myRunnable3);
    myThread3.start();
```

When I only call the `ChartThread` once time , it is work.
But it fail when I call the thread by three times via above code.
But it did not draw the chart one by one. Did I missing something ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why can't you just call `showOnMPChart` 3 times in a row?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is point of creating new thread and however you are calling the method from UI thread i.e main thread.

mActivity.runOnUiThread -->It will make your showOnMPChart to be called on Main thread. You could call showOnMPChart method one by one.